# Get number next to tilde

Tags: javascript, regex

Stuck on getting this to work as the standard lookbehind doesn't seem to support it

So the string I have is: `1~92 entries of 499 entries`

And I want to extract `92`

I've tried `/\d(?!~)/` and but that only gives me `9` if I use the `global` flag it ends up giving me 499 as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: `.match(/~(\d+)/)[1]`

Comment: @userMod2 may I know why you delete your previous question?

Comment: @Tushar - that gives me the tiddle

Comment: @AvinashRaj - hi - yes - i thought I had found the answer but found that JS doesnt support lookbehind

Comment: @userMod2 check my comment on your previous question. did you ever checked the index 1?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - tried that but it gives me the ~ as before the number as well

Comment: where https://jsfiddle.net/nq4fwkr2/1/ ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - apoloigies it does work. I was using https://regexr.com/ and didnt realise the `[1]` cannot be placed after the `/g` there. Thanks for your help

Comment: @userMod2 Does `'1~92 entries of 499 entries'.match(/~(\d+)/)[1]` gives you tilde? Did you try it

Answer (score 2):

In PHP where negative lookbehind works you could use `(?<=~)(?:[0-9]+)`
but in javascript it would be easier to just do:

```
var str = "1~92 entries of 499 entries";
var afterTilde = str.substr(str.indexOf("~")+1,2);
```

Or using regex:
`var regex = /(~)([0-9]{2})/g;`
and capture `group 2`.

[image]

```js
var regex = /(~)([0-9]{2})/;
var str = "1~92 entries of 499 entries";
alert(str.match(regex)[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you necessarily need a lookbehind. As per your example, the regex `[0-9]+\~([0-9]+)` would correctly capture `92` on group 1.

See it live on https://regex101.com/r/T4tSLD/1

Answer (score 0):

Use the tilde `~` to your advantage and capture the digits right after it:

```
/\d~(\d*)/
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var string = '1~92 entries of 499 entries';

let number = string.match(/\d~(\d*)/)[1];

console.log(number);
```